# Getting Maven missing dependency errors when compiling Confluence 3.5.13 source java dependency

Tags: java, maven

Describe the bug
When compiling a Maven-based SARL project, the compiler into Eclipse (not on the command-line interface) shows up an "Unknown" error at the first line of the pom.xml file.

To Reproduce
Steps to reproduce the behavior:

Create a Maven SARL project with the following pom file:

```
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>mygroup</groupId>
    <artifactId>myproject</artifactId>
    <version>0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <properties>
        <sarl.version>0.10.0-SNAPSHOT</sarl.version>
        <janus.version>2.0.10.0-SNAPSHOT</janus.version>
        <compiler.level>1.8</compiler.level>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javafx</groupId>
            <artifactId>jfxrt</artifactId>
            <version>${java.version}</version>
            <scope>system</scope>
            <systemPath>${java.home}/lib/ext/jfxrt.jar</systemPath>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.janusproject</groupId>
            <artifactId>io.janusproject.kernel</artifactId>
            <version>${janus.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.arakhne.afc.gis.ui</groupId>
            <artifactId>gisroadfx</artifactId>
            <version>${afc.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.arakhne.afc.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>mathphysics</artifactId>
            <version>${afc.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.arakhne.afc.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>mathstochastic</artifactId>
            <version>${afc.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.arakhne.afc.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>vmutils</artifactId>
            <version>${afc.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.dlsc.preferencesfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>preferencesfx-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.fxmisc.richtext</groupId>
            <artifactId>richtextfx</artifactId>
            <version>0.10.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.opencsv</groupId>
            <artifactId>opencsv</artifactId>
            <version>4.6</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${compiler.level}</source>
                    <target>${compiler.level}</target>
                    <encoding>${project.build.sourceEncoding}</encoding>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>io.sarl.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>sarl-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${sarl.version}</version>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${compiler.level}</source>
                    <target>${compiler.level}</target>
                    <encoding>${project.build.sourceEncoding}</encoding>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <name>Arakhne Lastest Builds</name>
            <id>org.arakhne.maven</id>
            <url>http://download.arakhne.org/arakhne/maven</url>
            <releases>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </releases>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
</project>
```

Compile
See error
Expected behavior
No error is expected.

System configuration:

SARL version: 0.9.0 and 0.10.0
SARL compiler:
Eclipse compiler without Maven
Eclipse compiler with Maven
Maven compiler on the command line
sarlc compiler
Java JDK version (with the manufacturer name): 1.8.0_201
Operating System:
Linux 64bits
Linux 32bits
Windows 64bits
Windows 32bits
MacOS 64bits